# Select count(*) from Table , Select * from Table dosent yeild any output

Tags: hive

I am trying to  build a managed table (which orc formatted ,bucketed and table properties is set to true for transnational  )on which i can run the update/Insert Statement In hive .
I am running this whole setup on AWS EMR  and the Hive version is 2.4.3 the default directory store the data is S3.

I am able to populate the table from another external table .

However am getting  select  count(*) as zero and  no output for select *

i dropped the table and recreated the table and repopulated the data .

The ANALYZE TABLE TABLE-NAME COMPUTE STATISTICS gives proper output .

Comment: Can you confirm if the table is partitioned and if yes have you ran MSCK repair to add partitions to the table?

Comment: The table is not partitioned  however when i see the  location of the s3 i see a folder structure  like this : s3//<database>/ <table >/delta_0000000_0000000/bucket_00000 bucket00001 etc